# Как вывести поля из другой модели в форму через FK?

Tags: django

Как из другой модели вывести поля в форму?

Т.е. хочу вывести поля CITY, GROUP, FIO из модели Numbers (и использовать их в качестве фильтра.), что бы добавить запись в модель "CLEAR", с указанием в поле "MEMBERS" - логин пользователя сделавшего запись.

в models.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField('Группа', max_length=5, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.group

сlass Cities(models.Model):

    city = models.CharField('Город', max_length=255, unique=True)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.city

class Numbers(models.Model):
    
    FIO = models.CharField('ФИО', max_length=255)
    WINLOGIN = models.CharField('Winlogin', max_length=255, unique=True)
    GROUP = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Группа')
    CITY = models.ForeignKey(Cities, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Город')
    DATE_ADD = models.DateTimeField('Дата добавления', auto_now_add=True)
    DATE_DELETE = models.DateTimeField('Дата удаления', blank=True, null=True)
    DATE_UPDATE = models.DateTimeField('Дата обновления', auto_now=True, null=True)
    MEMBERS = models.CharField('Логин изменившего', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.FIO

class Clear(models.Model):
   
    chas = [
        ('0', '0'), ('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'), ('6', '6'),
        ('7', '7'), ('8', '8'), ('9', '9'),
        ('10', '10'), ('11', '11'), ('12', '12'),
        ('13', '13'), ('14', '14'), ('15', '15'),
        ('16', '16'), ('17', '17'), ('18', '18'),
        ('19', '19'), ('20', '20'), ('21', '21'),
        ('22', '22'), ('23', '23')
    ]

    FIO = models.ForeignKey(Numbers, verbose_name='ФИО', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    DATE_CLEAR = models.DateField('Дата чистки')
    HOUR_FROM = models.CharField('с', max_length=2, choices=chas)
    HOUR_TO = models.CharField('по', max_length=2, choices=chas)
    COMMENT = models.CharField('Комментарий', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    DATE_ADD = models.DateTimeField('Дата добавления', auto_now_add=True)
    DATE_DELETE = models.DateTimeField('Дата удаления', blank=True, null=True)
    DATE_UPDATE = models.DateTimeField('Дата обновления', auto_now=True, null=True)
    MEMBERS = models.CharField('Логин изменившего', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

В urls.py

```
path('add_clear/', views.AddClear.as_view(), name='add_clear'),
```

В views.py

```
class AddClear(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'clear.add_clear'
    model = Clear
    template_name = 'clear/add_clear.html'
    form_class = ClearForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('clear')
    extra_context = {'title': 'Добавить в чистку'}
```

в Forms.py

```
class ClearForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Clear
        fields = ['FIO', 'DATE_CLEAR', 'HOUR_FROM', 'HOUR_TO', 'COMMENT']

    def clean(self):
        hour_from = self.cleaned_data['HOUR_FROM']
        hour_to = self.cleaned_data['HOUR_TO']
        if hour_from > hour_to:
            raise ValidationError('"Время C" должно быть меньше')
        return self.cleaned_data

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

ну и сам html шаблон:

```
{% block content %}
<h1 class="mt-3">{{ title }}</h1>

<div class="col-3 ml-4">

<form class="mt-4" action="{% url 'add_clear' %}" method = 'post'>
    {% csrf_token %}

{{ form }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-2">Добавить запись</button>


</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Нашел решение вот с таким вариантом, но и оно не получается:
Переписал forms.py

в такой вариант и получил ошибку:

```
class ClearForm(forms.Form):
    CITY = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Numbers.objects.values('CITY__city'))
    GROUP = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Numbers.objects.values('GROUP__group'))
    FIO = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Numbers.objects.values('FIO'))
    DATE_CLEAR = forms.DateInput()
    HOUR_FROM = forms.Select()
    HOUR_TO = forms.Select()
    COMMENT = forms.TextInput()


    def clean(self):
        hour_from = self.cleaned_data['HOUR_FROM']
        hour_to = self.cleaned_data['HOUR_TO']
        if hour_from > hour_to:
            raise ValidationError('"Время C" должно быть меньше')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

В результате получил ошибку:

```
Internal Server Error: /add_line2clear/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PPKorchagin\Documents\development\multi\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\PPKorchagin\Documents\development\multi\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PPKorchagin\Documents\development\multi\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 73, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PPKorchagin\Documents\development\multi\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 85, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PPKorchagin\Documents\development\multi\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PPKorchagin\Documents\development\multi\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 168, in get
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PPKorchagin\Documents\development\multi\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "C:\Users\PPKorchagin\Documents\development\multi\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "C:\Users\PPKorchagin\Documents\development\multi\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

Предполагаю, что нужно поправить вот эту часть

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

А так же установить зависимости по первым 3м полям, но не знаю как это сделать.
Буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1):

То есть вам надо что-бы FIO,CITY,GROUP были выведены?Ну по идее вам надо создать путь в urls для views(любой например: path('', views.index, name = 'index')  ), во views.py из моделей импортировать нужную вам и во views написать примерно такой код:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *



def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(Numbers.CITY)
```

Comment: Спасибо, за совет. Мне кажется для его использования придется создавать дополнительные маршруты url, не очень хотелось бы делать это. Но если ни чего не получится буду пробовать таким способом.